# window authentication in Office 365 from client context

Tags: authentication, office-365, office-integration, windows-authentication

I want to access office 365 list from window application. Is it possible to access using window authentication ? i don't want to pass user id and password

Comment: Is this 2013 or 2010? Most Office 365 do not use Windows authentication

Comment: office 2013. i want this in winapps and i dont want to pass crediatial

Answer (score 1):

Wictor Wilén has written an excellent guide for authenticating to Office 365 from Client object model [here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx).

But he, and everybody else, uses FedAuth with a username / password combination. This is due to the fact that this is how most configurations are set up.

Microsoft has released [this guide](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c#content) for doing Remote Authentication (Claims based!) via the Server Client Object Model but it is targeted for 2010, so it might not work 100%, or be the easiest way in 2013

I'm no expert in this, but wanted to submit you some great resources ti give you a starting point.

Comment: yes , i check this link and we have to pass username and password explicitly in this. i want to use window credential to login in office 365

Comment: In Wiléns you do, as I pointed out. But the Microsoft guide uses Claims which is the default authentication type for 2013

Comment: windows authentication is possible or not in office 365

Comment: It is possible if you have configured ADFS between your AD and Office 365

Comment: if adfs is configured then how we authenticate user without username name and password

Comment: If you look on my second link you see no single reference to a username or password..

Comment: in your second link, they will ask for username and password in browser and then they will store in cookie and give access

Comment: they will prompt a browser during authentication

Comment: You are correct

Comment: at this moment not can authenticate without credentials... believe that not is possible...